Bipartite colors do not match the interaction values
For some reason in my code, I'm trying to colour interactions over a certain limit one colour, and everything else I want grey. But my figure is coming up wrong every time and I don't understand why - the code is very simple so it should work?
Here is my code:
plotweb(data.mat,
        method="normal",
        text.rot = 90,
        labsize = 1,
        y.width.low = 0.05,
        col.high = "#66A61E",
        #col.interaction = "#E6AB02",
        col.low = "#E7298A",
        bor.col.interaction =  NA,
        arrow="none",
        empty=TRUE,
        plot.axes=FALSE,
        ybig=1,
        col.interaction = (ifelse(data.mat[,] < 1000,
                                  adjustcolor("grey80", alpha.f=0.5),
                                  adjustcolor("#E6AB02", alpha.f = 0.5))))

Here is my dataset:
> dput(data.mat)
structure(c(7336L, 1640L, 26293L, 111533L, 71255L, 161705L, 104046L, 
169975L, 395822L, 153999L, 6780L, 10866L, 131162L, 239110L, 130786L, 
88922L, 46725L, 99169L, 109625L, 203947L, 2258L, 550L, 47109L, 
1813L, 362753L, 14451L, 17025L, 30251L, 308L, 34412L, 11L, 0L, 
56988L, 1360L, 4L, 5L, 107L, 31L, 56L, 868L, 31775L, 31L, 327L, 
19L, 180L, 4284L, 77L, 27L, 0L, 854L, 5L, 143L, 4622L, 264L, 
7945L, 51L, 14545L, 32L, 8L, 126L, 66L, 0L, 6L, 14130L, 5L, 9L, 
165L, 1017L, 5L, 115L, 65L, 5L, 9572L, 77L, 820L, 165L, 521L, 
788L, 17L, 538L), dim = c(10L, 8L), dimnames = list(c("Arctium lappa", 
"Cichorium intybus", "Circium arvense", "Circium vulgare", "Hypericum perforatum", 
"Leucanthemum vulgare", "Plantago lanceolata", "Trifolium pratense", 
"Trifolium repens", "Tripleurospermum inodorum"), c("Cladosporium", 
"Alternaria", "Aureobasidium", "X....1", "Golovinomyces", "Podosphaera", 
"Ampelomyces", "X....2")))

All the large interactions should be coloured yellow, and everything else I want grey.
Output image: The thicker bars should all be yellow, and thin bars/thin lines should be grey but it's not happening.


share the output/image youre receiving please

Added figure - I made the grey a bit darker on my end because it wasn't showing up clearly on the image here.
